# Module parse failed: .../build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css Unexpected token (5:3) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Using `react-datetimepicker-bootstrap` I get the following issue:

```
ERROR in ./~/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css
Module parse failed: /Users/cchilders/work_projects/project/node_modules/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css Unexpected token (5:3)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|  * version : 4.17.47
|  * https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/
|  */.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget{list-style:none}.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget.dropdown-menu{display:block;...entire source...

ERROR in ./~/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
Module parse failed: /Users/cchilders/work_projects/project/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css Unexpected token (5:83)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|  * Copyright 2011-2016 Twitter, Inc.
|  * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
|  *//*! normalize.css v3.0.3 | MIT License | github.com/necolas/normalize.css */html{font-family:sans-serif;...entire source...
| /*# sourceMappingURL=bootstrap.min.css.map */
 @ ./~/react-datetimepicker-bootstrap/build/App.js 11:0-47
 @ ./client/controllers/SOPOrderHoldController.js
 @ ./client/main.js
 @ multi webpack-hot-middleware/client ./client/main.js
```

I know this because commenting out

```
import DateTimePicker from 'react-datetimepicker-bootstrap';
```

fixes the problem and React works as normal. The source is at https://github.com/iMasterAle/react-datetimepicker-bootstrap

I looked at a similar error message but it talked about changing a webpack.config issue I don't have. Nothing specific to this package comes up on search

webpack.config-dev.js:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  //devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  entry: [
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
    './client/main.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: require("path").resolve('./assets'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ],
  externals: {
      jquery: 'var jQuery'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'react-hmre'],
          plugins: ['transform-decorators-legacy']
        }
      },
      {
          include: /\.json$/,
          loader: 'json-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "starter-kit",
  "version": "1.1.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack",
    "start": "python app.py",
    "devserver": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.4.5",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-react-hmre": "^1.1.1",
    "coffee-loader": "^0.7.3",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
    "morgan": "^1.7.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.2",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.3",
    "style-loader": "^0.16.1",
    "webpack": "^2.0.0",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.9.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.15.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.23.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.16.0",
    "bootstrap-daterangepicker": "^2.1.25",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "dotenv": "^4.0.0",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "highcharts": "^5.0.10",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "moment": "^2.17.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.11",
    "morgan": "^1.7.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "prop-types": "^15.5.8",
    "react": "^0.14.7",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.30.7",
    "react-bootstrap-datetimerangepicker": "^2.0.3",
    "react-data-components": "^1.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.7",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.2",
    "react-router": "^3.0.2",
    "react-simpletabs": "^0.7.0",
    "react-tabs": "^0.8.2",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-logger": "^2.8.1",
    "redux-promise-middleware": "^4.2.0",
    "redux-sequence-action": "^0.2.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "sendgrid": "^5.0.1",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^2.0.2"
  }
}
```

The package in question is installed. It does not have to be deleted from `node_modules` for the issue to go away, I just uncommented the import line. I want to use this or a similar datetimepicker package, the datetimerangepicker is used elsewhere and needs to stay. I do have bootstrap included elsewhere, but I tried removing any other bootstrap includes and that didn't help.

Comment: could u try removing the comments from the file : node_modules\eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker\build\css\bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css ?

Comment: This didn't help